# How do I add the active class to the first dynamic tab instead of the static tab in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having an issue with ui-bootstrap's tabsets. I have one static tab (Other) and the rest are added using ng-repeat. I can't get the first dynamically loaded tab to be active, instead it always adds the active class to the static one. How can I add the active class to the first dynamic tab? I have removed some clutter for clarity.

the documentation is here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="room in rooms" heading="{{room.Name}}">
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="item in room track by $index">
        <div>
          <p>{{item.Title}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Other">
    <form name="customItem">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customItem.Title" placeholder="Title" />
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addCustomItem(customItem.Title)">Add custom item</button>
    </form>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try the ng-class in the tab's ng-repeat and you could check if it is the first element or not with this code: `ng-class="{'active': $index==0}"`

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="room in rooms" heading="{{room.Name}}" ng-class="{'active': $index==0}">
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="item in room track by $index">
        <div>
          <p>{{item.Title}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Other">
    <form name="customItem">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customItem.Title" placeholder="Title" />
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addCustomItem(customItem.Title)">Add custom item</button>
    </form>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```